# zsh function output removes leading whitespace

Tags: zsh, echo

Consider the following two commands and their outcome:

```
14:57 : echo $(echo "  ABC")
ABC

14:57 : echo "  ABC"
  ABC
```

Version of zsh: `zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0)`

Why does the first one remove the leading whitespaces? I can't find an explanation or justification in the doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `echo ABC` and `echo         ABC` gives the same output: `ABC`, and the first command `echo $(echo "  ABC")` ==> `echo   ABC` ==> `ABC`. Multiple spaces are just removed by the shell, so `echo` doesn't even know how many of them were present in the command-line.

You can preserve spaces by quoting the whole expression in the following way:

```
$ echo "$(echo "  ABC")"
    ABC
```

or

```
$ echo "$(echo '  ABC')"
    ABC
```

Comment: No, it's wrong to make that parallel. It's completely different things: on one end the shell parser/tokenizer (in `echo    ABC`), on the other end the implicit split operator (split+glob in other shells) applied upon unquoted command substitution.

Answer (score 5):

The result of a [command substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution) is broken into words using characters from `IFS` as separators, unless the command substitution is in double quotes. Thus `"  ABC"` is split into a list of words, which contains one element `"ABC"`. Use `echo "$(echo "  ABC")"` to use the result of the command susbtitution as a string.

Unlike normal Bourne/POSIX-style shells, zsh does not treat the words resulting from the command substitution as glob patterns: `echo $(echo "*")` prints `*`, not a list of files (unless the option `glob_subst` is set). Also unlike normal Bourne/POSIX-style shells, splitting is only performed on unquoted command substitutions, not on unquoted variable substitutions, except that empty words resulting from an unquoted variable substitution are removed.